# Automating converstion of files from .MQO to .OBJ

Tags: batch, macros, 3d, 3d-modeling, modeling

I have a full folder of .MQO 3D model files that I converted from .DAT 3D model files These files can be imported with the program "Metasequoia 4".

I want to import the .MQO file and then export it as an .OBJ.

I have tested this process, and it works.

however, I have around 2600 files that need to undergo this same process.

How can I automate this process?

1. import next .MQO from a specific folder in Metasequoia.
2. export this .MQO as an .OBJ.
3. save this new .OBJ into the folder.
4. repeat

Programs like photoshop have the ability to automate processes in this way. I don't want to meticulously go through 2600 files, although I will if there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really great program here:

[Batch 3D .X format to .X format](http://3doc.i3dconverter.com/index.html)

This program allows the user to select a containing folder and then it will iterate through all the files to be converted and convert them to the desired format!

it isn't perfect, it causes some holes in the mesh, but these are minor for me.

Now I have all my .objs!

problem solved.

Neat!